# ffmpeg "filtergraph join" to use copy of channels and preserve input channel configuration (format - s32_le)

Tags: windows, audio, ffmpeg

Command that I am using  is below, with that command I am getting 8 channel output.wav.

```
ffmpeg.exe    -i one.wav -i two.wav -i three.wav -i four.wav \
-i five.wav -i six.wav -i seven.wav -i eight.wav \
-filter_complex '[0:0][1:0][2:0][3:0][4:0][5:0][6:0] \
[7:0]join=8:channel_layout=octagonal'  output.wav
```

All input files one.wav, two.wav so on eight.wav are 32khz,s32le and one channel. but, output generated is output.wav which is s16le, 32khz.

I can make output s32le with below command,

```
ffmpeg.exe -i one.wav -i two.wav -i three.wav -i four.wav \
-i five.wav -i six.wav -i seven.wav -i eight.wav \
-filter_complex '[0:0][1:0][2:0][3:0][4:0][5:0][6:0] \
[7:0]join=8:channel_layout=octagonal'  -acodec pcm_s32le output.wav
```

But, above command seems todo conversion from s16_le to s32_le (i.e one.wav doesn't match with output.wav first channel completely). However what I want is to directly copy data from input channels since audio format of all input files is same as expected audio format of output file channels (output.wav)

is there way to instruct filter_graph todo processing at pcm_s32le ?

Here is link to log with loglevel set to debug,
https://pastebin.com/ms4x1fLz

```
MediaInfo.exe one.wav
General
Complete name                            : one.wav
Format                                   : Wave
File size                                : 6.50 MiB
Duration                                 : 53 s 280 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 1 024 kb/s

Audio
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Codec ID                                 : 1
Duration                                 : 53 s 280 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 024 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 32.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 32 bits
Stream size                              : 6.50 MiB (100%)
```

Comment: *"seems todo conversion from s16_le to s32_le"* How are you verifying that? The auto resampler should use s32p internally between filters (refer to log with `-loglevel debug` option).

Comment: sure, will check logs, I just compared my original channels and final output channels, They don't match. Default output of command without acodec options is also s16 even though my inputs are s32

Comment: How did you compare the original channels and final output channels? Yes, default output encoder for WAV is pcm_s16le, but you are manually setting pcm_s32le, so I am not yet convinced there is any s16 conversion given what is shown in the log.

Comment: I compared results with audacity. output.wav first channel and one.wav first channel when I invert one of them and compare I see difference. Plain copy I feel shouldn't have that difference

Comment: I see from debug logs resampler for each channel which does convert between s32 and s32p and finally s32p to s32 . what is P here ?

Comment: P is planar. Note that, if I recall correctly, audacity converts the input to a 32-bit float working file.

Comment: It does for both input and output file and effect is nullified

Answer (score 0):

I believe you came to the wrong conclusion by using Audacity to compare. There should be no s16 conversion with your command using `-acodec pcm_s32le`. You can check by adding `-loglevel debug` to your command and refer to the `auto_resampler` lines in the log.

The input and output should match. Using the [hash muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hash) to verify:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel error -i one.wav -c:a copy -f hash -
SHA256=e56af84aea634ba4686348a90b657e1536610bf977b3604a9eb5b2901ccdeea3

ffmpeg -loglevel error -i output.wav -af "channelsplit=channel_layout=octagonal:channels=FL" -c:a pcm_s32le -f hash -
SHA256=e56af84aea634ba4686348a90b657e1536610bf977b3604a9eb5b2901ccdeea3
```

Comment: I see some of these logs and also hash is different,                                        
 [AVFilterGraph @ 0000020298600980] query_formats: 11 queried, 3 merged, 27 already done, 0 delayed
[auto_resampler_0 @ 0000020298672300] picking s32p out of 6 ref:s32
[auto_resampler_0 @ 0000020298672300] [SWR @ 0000020298672400] Using s32p internally between filters
[auto_resampler_0 @ 0000020298672300] ch:1 chl:mono fmt:s32 r:32000Hz -> ch:1 chl:mono fmt:s32p r:32000Hz

Comment: $ ffmpeg -loglevel error -i output.wav -af "channelsplit=channel_layout=octagonal:channels=FL" -c:a pcm_s32le -f hash -
SHA256=a89a70bbdf876d79119078eb0b02d0bfd841454620d81555dfc99d25fd1611c3
$ ffmpeg -loglevel error -i one.wav -c:a copy -f hash -
SHA256=1b851da85debab75ea244e5611df232b048312c4a91f0e1f01a5d66e3d99e5b4

Comment: @vishwanathpatil Provide the full log from your join command. You can edit your question to include it or use a pastebin site and provide a link. Also provide a link to `one.wav` if possible.

Comment: I updated with details, even though I can't share file

Comment: can you take a look